# How to quantify line shape with ImageJ macro

Tags: macros, line, shapes, imagej

I would like to quantify the shape of a line on the wings of butterflies which can vary from quite straight to squiggly similar to the horizon in a landscape, or similar to a graph (per each x value there is only 1 y value), although overall orientation varies. My idea is to use the free hand tool to trace the line of interest and then let an ImageJ macro quantify it (automating this may be tricky because there are many line-like structures). Two traits seem useful to me;

1. the proportion between the length of the drawn line and the straight line between the end points.
2. 'Dispersion' of the line such as calculated in the Directionality plugin.

Other traits such as what proportion of the line is below or under the straight line that connects the extremes may also be useful.
How can this be coded? I am building an interactive macro that prompts the measuring of various traits for an open image.
Hopefully the below (non-functional) code will convey what I am trying to do.

```
//line shape analysis
run("Select None");
setTool("free hand");
waitForUser("Trace the line between point A and B");
length= measure();
String command = "Directionality";
new PlugInFilterRunner(da, command, "nbins=60, start=-90, method=gradient");
get data...

//to get distance between points A and B
run("Select None");
    setTool("multipoint");
    waitForUser("Distances","Click on points A and B  \nAfter they appear, you can click and drag them if you need to readjust.");
    getSelectionCoordinates(xCoordinates, yCoordinates);
 
    xcoordsp = xCoordinates;
    ycoordsp = yCoordinates;
makeLine(xcoordsp[0], ycoordsp[0], xcoordsp[1], ycoordsp[1]);
    List.setMeasurements;
    StrLength = List.getValue("Length");
```

I have looked online for solutions but found surprisingly little about this relatively simple issue.

warm regards,
Freerk

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution to determine to what extent the line deviates from a straight line between pint A and B. The 'straightness' is the proportion between the two measures.

```
    // To meausure line length to compare to length of straight line aka Euclidean distance
    run("Select None");
    setTool("polyline");
    waitForUser("Trace the line between point V5 and V3 by clickinmg at each corner finish by double click"); // Points V5 and V3 refer to point A and B  It can be adjusted 
    run("Measure");
    getStatistics(Perim);
    FLR=Perim; // FLR For forewing lenght real

    // to get Euclidian distance between points A and B
    run("Select None");
    setTool("multipoint");
    waitForUser("Distances","Click on points A and B  \nAfter they appear, you can click and drag them if you need to readjust.");
    getSelectionCoordinates(xCoordinates, yCoordinates); 
    xcoordsp = xCoordinates;
    ycoordsp = yCoordinates;
    makeLine(xcoordsp[0], ycoordsp[0], xcoordsp[1], ycoordsp[1]);
    List.setMeasurements;
    FLS = List.getValue("Length"); // FLS For forewing length straight
    }
```

I would still be grateful for more sophistcated line parameters